# I keep getting an IntegrityError when i try to use Faker to populate my script

Tags: python, django

I've tried to delete the migrations folder and then redo the makemigrations process but i keep getting the same IntegrityError and it is probably coming from the migrations code itself but i don't understand it as the creation of the code was automatic by Django. The code below is my population script.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "first_project.settings")

import django
django.setup()

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic
from faker import Faker




fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()


def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        top = add_topic()

        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg, date=fake-date)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('populating script')
    populate(20)
    print('populating complete')
```

the code for the models is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.top_name


class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.str(self.date)
```

and then what popped up in my prompt

```
populating script
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 581, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
first_app.models.DoesNotExist: Webpage matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: first_app_webpage.topic_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\Desktop\My_Django_Stuff\first_project\pop_app.py", line 38, in <module>
    populate(20)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\Desktop\My_Django_Stuff\first_project\pop_app.py", line 31, in populate
    webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 588, in get_or_create
    return self.create(**params), True
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1416, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dr. Tenotea\anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: first_app_webpage.topic_id
```

Comment: can you please paste the error so we can understand better.

Comment: Most likely a required field that's not being set - will need to see the error and the models.

Comment: i have added the error and the models code already